# Extracting elements wherever JArray in json

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

Lets see, the json can be dynamic and can probably have number of nested arrays within any property.

Example:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "0001",
            "name": "Cake",
            "batters": {
                "batter": [
                    {
                        "id": "1001",
                        "type": "Regular"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1002",
                        "type": "Chocolate"
                    },
                    {
                        "dry": [
                            {
                                "id": "1003",
                                "type": "Devil's Food"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "other": [
                    {
                        "id": "1004",
                        "type": "Home Food"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "topping": [
                {
                    "id": "5002",
                    "type": "Glazed"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5005",
                    "type": "Sugar"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "0002",
            "name": "Sweets"
        }
    ]
}
```

A simple list should return elements as:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1001",
        "type": "Regular"
    },
    {
        "id": "1002",
        "type": "Chocolate"
    },
    {
        "id": "1003",
        "type": "Devil's Food"
    },
    {
        "id": "1004",
        "type": "Home Food"
    },
    {
        "id": "5002",
        "type": "Glazed"
    },
    {
        "id": "5005",
        "type": "Sugar"
    },
    {
        "id": "0002",
        "name": "Sweets"
    }
]
```

Please note:
Json can by anything, no property can be used for extraction , just knowing that what needed is stuff inside an JArray.

What i have tried so far but its just a start:

```
public static bool ParseJsonArray(JToken token, List<string> extracts, string parentLocation = "")
        {
            if (token.HasValues)
            {
                foreach (JToken child in token.Children())
                {
                    if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
                    {
                        parentLocation += ((JProperty)token).Name;
                        extracts.Add(token.ToString());
                    }
                    ParseJsonArray(child, extracts, parentLocation);
                }
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

`token` here is the parsed dynamic json.

Comment: dynamic data = Json.Decode(json); - does this work for you?

Comment: What about `{ "id": "0001", "name": "Cake" }`?  Is that supposed to be included in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though you want to recursively find all JArray entries that do not themselves contain nested arrays.  Let's call these "leaf" array entries.  I say that because you don't include the following non-leaf entry in your results:

```
    {
        "id": "0001",
        "name": "Cake"
    }
```

That being said, you can find leaf array entries with the following extension method:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<JToken> LeafArrayEntries(this JContainer container)
    {
        var nonLeafEntries = new HashSet<JToken>(container.DescendantsAndSelf()
            .OfType<JArray>()
            .SelectMany(a => a.Ancestors().Where(p => p.Type != JTokenType.Property)));
        return container.DescendantsAndSelf().Where(c => c.Parent is JArray && !nonLeafEntries.Contains(c));
    }
}
```

Then put the returned items in an array of their own with:

```
var leafItemArray = new JArray(rootJContainer.LeafArrayEntries());
```

Comment: Thnks buddy, it does what i need. Can you edit your answer to include `{
        "id": "0001",
        "name": "Cake"
    }` as well?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm not good at English.
I just finished analyzing newtonjson.
And I found these..

1. { ... } is JObject.
   JObject has JProperties.
2. JProperty : "key":value(JValue, JObject, JArray)
   The value object of JProperty is JProperty.Value.
3. [ ... ] is JArray
   JValue, JObject, Jarray can be item of JArray.
4. JValue is scalar value.
5. Value of JToken(if it's JProperty) is JToken.First

Every object can be JToken.

Your whole data is one JObject(root).
I'll call it as jo.
Your jo has one JProperty, key is "items" and value is JArray.
JArray has 2 JObject items.
First JObject item has 4 properties.
...and so on...

You need to make a recursive function.

Roughly...(I did'nt run this)

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> listResult = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
parseJson(jo, listResult);

void parseJson(JToken tok, List<Dictionary<string, object>> listRes)
{
    if (tok is JObject)
    {
        JObject jo = (JObject)tok;

        if (jo.Parent is JArray
            && jo.Count == 2 && jo.ContainsKey("id") && jo.ContainsKey("type")
        {
            //Found
            Dictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            dic.Add("id", jo["id"].Value<object>());
            dic.Add("type", jo["type"].Value<object>());

            listRes.Add(dic);
        }
        else
        {
            //Continue searching
            foreach (JProperty prop in tok)
            {
                parseJson(prop.First, listRes);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (tok is JArray)
    {
        foreach (JToken item in tok)
        {
            parseJson(item, listRes);
        }
    }
}
```

And, make string from result List.